# Неполный заголовок страницы поиска

Tags: дефект, поиск

Посмотрите на заголовок страницы поиска по следующему запросу:

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=[git]%20is%3aa

> Сообщения с наивысшим рейтингом, содержащие термины 'is:a' - Stack Overflow на русском

В запросе ведь ещё и метка есть, почему о ней не сказано в заголовке? Ну и условие на поиск только ответов в идеале должно как-то понятнее представляться.

Думаю, должно быть так:

> Вопросы по метке [git] с наивысшим рейтингом - Stack Overflow на русском

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, попробуйте сформулировать яснее.

Comment: @KromStern речь о заголовке страницы.

Comment: Полагаю, что поисковый движок выделяет метки из запроса, и хотя в поисковой строке оно выглядит как было, поиск идёт отдельно по меткам, а уже в пределах меток по указанным словам.